# Render output from dynamic JSON response

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I will get dynamic JSON response based on given input.
Like this

```
{ results:
 [ { email: 'test@test.com',
    name: 'aaaaaa',
    phone: "987654321",
    createdAt: '2015-07-08T10:51:07.715Z',
    updatedAt: '2015-07-08T12:17:38.924Z',
   },
  { email: 'test12@test.com',
    name: 'bbbbbb',
    phone: "9845454510",
    createdAt: '2015-07-08T10:58:07.715Z',
    updatedAt: '2015-07-08T12:47:31.924Z', 
   } 
  ]
}
```

and like this

```
{ results:
     [ { appName: 'myTest',
        key: 'MSZAD',
        env:"dev"
        },
      { appName: 'HelloWorldApp',
        key: 'TXCVD',
        env:"prod"
       } 
      ]
    }
```

How do I render Like this below,

For 1st example

```
email           name      phone
-----------------------------------
test@test.com   aaaaaa    987654321
test12@test.com bbbbbb    9845454510
```

For 2nd example

```
appname       key     env
--------------------------
myTest        MSZAD   dev
HelloWorldApp TXCVD   prod
```

If the response is same, I can do with simple loop with static title. But the response is dynamic. Only `results` in the response will be same in all response.

**Edit**:

Code I have tried so far

```
var collection = JSON.parse(body).results;
     for (var i = 0; i<collection.length; i++) {
        var obj = collection[i];
        for (var key in obj) { 
            console.log(key+':'obj[key]);
        }

      }
```

Output:

```
email: test@test.com
name:aaaaaa
phone : 987654321
createdAt:...
updatedAt: ...

email: test12@test.com
name:bbbbbb
phone : 98454510
createdAt:...
updatedAt:...
```

Comment: sorry whats the question? where is the code you need help with? you've tagged ndoe and javascript and shown neither. hwhat have you tried? wplease explain what you mean by 'render'? to the console? in a log? in html?

Comment: where is your code. what have been tried by you

Comment: how many dynamic outputs are there?

Comment: @atmd Printing result in console also fine, then I can modify it. I can able to do for same response . But failed to do for dynamic response.

Comment: structure is same just a simple for loop that will work fine in your same just displaying right. like for(key in reponse.results[0]) { keys } apply same for all remaining objects in the array

Comment: Can you show what code you have so far

Comment: @raghavendra response are actually table data from backend. So number of dynamic outputs based on number of tables.

Comment: yes not a problem use for in loop at second level

Comment: @LearneRツ i think you have use different iterators or for loop based on response.

Comment: try this https://jsfiddle.net/wLn738vg/ change your data as required

Comment: try the above fiddle may that will help you

Comment: @raghavendra it does the trick. Thanks. You could have post this in answer section.

Comment: no i will try to post now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
var data = { results:
 [ { email: 'test@test.com',
    name: 'aaaaaa',
    phone: "987654321",
    createdAt: '2015-07-08T10:51:07.715Z',
    updatedAt: '2015-07-08T12:17:38.924Z',
   },
  { email: 'test12@test.com',
    name: 'bbbbbb',
    phone: "9845454510",
    createdAt: '2015-07-08T10:58:07.715Z',
    updatedAt: '2015-07-08T12:47:31.924Z', 
   } 
  ]
};

var headers = data.results[0];
var hd = '';
for(var key in headers) {
    hd += key+' ';
}
console.log(hd);
for(var index in  data.results) {
    var obj = data.results[index];
    var out = '';
    for(var key in obj) {
        out += obj[key]+' ';
    }
    console.log(out);
}
```